# Updating multiple rows from temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have summed a load a averages for our customers using temp tables and would like to update our customers tables with these new values.  I can do single updates etc but would like to update as a set but keep getting the 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows...' from the second block of code (all values in #tcAvgs are fine.

```
create table #tcAvgs
(
    AccNo varchar(10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
    AvgFrame float,
    AvgValue float,
    AvgJobs float 
)
INSERT INTO #tcAvgs (AccNo, AvgFrame, AvgValue, AvgJobs)
SELECT t.accno, ROUND(t.TFrame/t.ccount ,2),ROUND(t.TValue/t.ccount , 2), ROUND( t.CCount/6 ,2)
FROM #tcTotals t


UPDATE c
SET c.AvgFrames = a.AvgFrame,
    c.AvgJobs = a.AvgJobs,
    c.AvgValue = a.AvgValue
FROM customers c join #tcAvgs a on c.AccountNo = a.AccNo
```

I've looked at a load of different ways of doing it and they all seem to give the same error, i'm wondering if I have to bite the bullet and loop through the temp table doing individual updates?  Am i missing something fundamental about SQLs ability to do multiple updates (albeit many single updates).

Any push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... things like procedural programming extensions are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: And what is the exact issue? I don't see any subquery here in what you've posted that could return more than one value. The `UPDATE` query seems fine at first sight - and it **should** work like that. Can't see anything wrong with it. Is this the complete and actual code? Or are you keeping something from us?? (*naughty naughty*)

Comment: Nono, this is the complete code that's what I can't understand. Example of #tcAvgs data  X024 / 2.69 / 633.41 / 25.83 and its just meant to update the matching customer record by the Account Number (eg X024)

Comment: [See this SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03b04/2) - seems to work for me.

Comment: Are `AccNo` from the temporary table and `AccountNo` from `Customers` the same datatype??

Comment: Yep same data type, could a trigger on the customer table be affecting it perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is solely for people who have found that a trigger is preventing the solution provided by @Andrew Bickerton And  @marc_s (and myself originally ^^)

```
DECLARE @Counter INT
DECLARE @AccNo varchar(10)
DECLARE @AvgFrames float
DECLARE @AvgJobs float
DECLARE @AvgValue float

SET @Counter = 1
WHILE @Counter <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tcAvgs)
BEGIN
    --update variables
    SELECT @AccNo = t.AccNo, @AvgFrames = t.AvgFrame, @AvgJobs = t.AvgJobs, @AvgValue = t.AvgValue 
    FROM #tcAvgs t
    WHERE t.Id = @Counter

    UPDATE customers
    SET AvgFrames = @AvgFrames,
        AvgValues = @AvgValue,
        AvgJobs = @AvgJobs
    WHERE AccountNo = @AccNo

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END
```

Comment: The correct answer is, of course, to get the triggers altered so that they can *cope* with multi-row updates (inserts, deletes), rather than to leave them broken and have to implement workarounds like this.

Comment: This is 100% true, unfortunately we just don't have the luxury of time now to review and modify the triggers that are on it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is SQL Server complaining that you have more than 1 matching row in your #tcAvgs table, so it doesn't know what values you want to set the row in customers to.

If you run:

```
create table #tcAvgs
(
    AccNo varchar(10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
    AvgFrame float,
    AvgValue float,
    AvgJobs float 
)
INSERT INTO #tcAvgs (AccNo, AvgFrame, AvgValue, AvgJobs)
SELECT t.accno, ROUND(t.TFrame/t.ccount ,2),ROUND(t.TValue/t.ccount , 2), ROUND( t.CCount/6 ,2)
FROM #tcTotals t

SELECT c.AccountNo, COUNT(a.AccountNo) as NumRows
FROM customers c join #tcAvgs a on c.AccountNo = a.AccNo 
GROUP BY c.AccountNo
HAVING COUNT(a.AccountNo) > 1
```

you will find the records that are causing a problem.  My guess is that it's:

```
INSERT INTO #tcAvgs (AccNo, AvgFrame, AvgValue, AvgJobs)
SELECT t.accno, ROUND(t.TFrame/t.ccount ,2),ROUND(t.TValue/t.ccount , 2), ROUND( t.CCount/6 ,2)
FROM #tcTotals t
```

you might need it to be:

```
INSERT INTO #tcAvgs (AccNo, AvgFrame, AvgValue, AvgJobs)
SELECT t.accno, AVG(ROUND(t.TFrame/t.ccount ,2)),AVG(ROUND(t.TValue/t.ccount , 2)), AVG(ROUND( t.CCount/6 ,2))
FROM #tcTotals t
GROUP BY t.accno
```

Comment: This is what I thought it was originally, but the accno is grouped in a previous temp table and they're all unique.  There's definately no duplicates I ran some queries on the result set to double check :(

Comment: I'd suggest doing a controlled experiment ie:  `UPDATE customers SET AvgFrame = a.AvgFrame FROM (SELECT '1' as AccNo, 0.1 as AvgFrame UNION SELECT '2' as AccNo, 0.2 as AvgFrame) a WHERE a.AccNo = [customers].AccNo` this will prove if there is something else preventing multi-row updates (trigger perhaps) or if it's something in your query

Comment: Yes, it's definately the triggers on the table, it all works fine now i've disabled it.  Unfortunately I don't have the option to leave them that way. So i'll have to use a while loop I guess. :(  Thanks for your help everyone.